# MVC3 Best Practise with Collections in Razor

Tags: c#, razor

May have been asked before, but not that I could find.

I'm simply wondering from those of you with vastly more experience than I:

What is the best practise for displaying, editing, adding new collections in Razor format?

To elaborate a bit more on what I mean - I'm primarily comparing using an EditorTemplate for a collection of strongly typed objects to only show some of the properties on said object, as opposed to using a foreach loop in the Razor code itself, on the view, and explictly detailing the property values there.

Sample:

EditorTemplate:

```
<div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo, "Foo")
    </div>
    <div >
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Fishfood, new { style = "width: 200px" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Main View:

```
<div>
     @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FooBarItems)
<div>
```

OR:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Foo", item.Foo)
    </div>
    <div >
        @Html.TextBox(item.Fishfood, new { style = "width: 200px" })
    </div>
}
```

They are practically similar in every way but I wondered if I was missing anything!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is better. I always use editor/display templates. This allows me to reuse the template in multiple locations. Also in the case of editor template it generates proper names and ids of the input fields which is not the case when you write a `foreach` loop. If you wanted to do this *inline* you would have to use a `for` loop with an index but things get ugly.

So everytime you need to dislpay/edit a collection of something in an ASP.NET MVC application define a display/editor template for this something and then call it from the main view on the collection property.

Another way to say the same is the following: everytime you write a `foreach` or `for` loop in a Razor view an alarm should ring telling you that there is a better way :-)

Comment: I have been trying to where possible myself. However is there much of a difference? I'm attempting to convince my boss that it IS the way collections are displayed in Razor, but I'm only going off what I've read. I totally agree that templates are more useful, save code duplication and the like.

Comment: @MattTolliday, yes there is a difference: names of input fields in the case of editor templates will be correctly generated for the default model binder to correctly fetch the values back in the POST action.